# Scroll the text at the same time with the images using ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift3

I'm trying to implement a SlideShow when the user first starts the application and everything works fine, I can scroll between images and the text changes when I slide, but there is a problem. The text doesn't slide at the same time with the image, it only changes when i stop sliding through screens.

What I would like to do is scroll the labels and the text at the same time I'm scrolling the image. I know that a workaround would be to put the text on the image but it's not an option for me in this particular case. Is there a way I can make the elements from the view scroll at the same time as the images?

What I got so far:

```
class SlidesViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var titleView: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //1
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height)
    let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.height
    //2
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.text = "Sweettutos.com is your blog of choice for Mobile tutorials"
    textView.textColor = .red
    //3
    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "slide1")
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "slide2")
    let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*2, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "slide3")
    let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*3, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "slide4")

    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgThree)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgFour)
    //4
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollView.frame.width * 4, height:self.scrollView.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    // Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends
    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1
    // Change the indicator
    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage);
    // Change the text accordingly
    if Int(currentPage) == 0{
        textView.text = "Description of slide 1"
        titleView.text = "Text Silde 1"
    }else if Int(currentPage) == 1{
        textView.text = "Description of slide 2"
        titleView.text = "Text Silde 2"
    }else if Int(currentPage) == 2{
        textView.text = "Description of slide 3"
        titleView.text = "Text Silde 3"
        pageControl.isHidden = false
    }else {
        textView.text = "Description of slide 4"
        titleView.text = "Text Silde 3"
        pageControl.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is behaving exactly as it's intended, i.e. *after* your `scrollView` has stopped movement. If you're looking to do it on the fly, use `scrollViewDidScroll` instead.

Comment: Thank you. It does solve the problem i have. But is it possible using the scrollview to make the text remain in the middle of the image and scroll with the image? At the current state the text changes when changing the slide but it remains in the middle of the view.

Comment: You will have to come up with a complex formula to calculate the offset of text. How complex, is upto you.